# Get jquery datetimepicker to grid to minutes

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm currently using http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ . 
I want when the user drags the "minute" slider to increase by 15. So minutes could only be be 0,15,30,45. How could that be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check example #6 on the link you sent, you can set the 'stepMinute' option:

```
$('...').datetimepicker({
    stepMinute: 15
});
```

Have fun!

Comment: Ahh.... I didn't see that.. Thank you! I'll mark it as the answer in 10 minutes :)